# Alternative for profile document

Tags: javascript, xpages, profile

I'm following the [article](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2010/09/application-configuration-/-parameters-in-xpages.html) that tells us how to store global parameters, how profile documents work for classic Notes applications. I followed the steps of the article and implemented the classes according to the necessary globular parameters, however when I call a method of the javascript object the error below happens. I'm kind of confused because calling this same method elsewhere in the application works normally. Below is the code for the javascript object, implemented as the example in the article.

Script interpreter error, line=12, col=21: [TypeError] Error calling method 'getDbRH()' on an object of type 'java.util.HashMap [Dynamic Java Wrapper, java.util.HashMap]'

```
var dbFotoConfig = { 

getDbFoto : function ( ) { 

    var cache = this. getCacheObject ( ) ; 

    var result = cache.get( "DbFoto" ) ; 

    if (result == null ) {

        // Here is where you would do @DBSomething or worse
        var visao:NotesView=database.getView("Configuracoes")
        var doc:NotesDocument=visao.getFirstDocument();
        if (doc!=null)
        {

            result=  [doc.getItemValueString("servidor_foto"),doc.getItemValueString("base_foto"),doc.getItemValueString("visao_foto")]
            cache.put("DbFoto",result)
             sessionScope.put ( "dbFotoConfig" ,cache )
        }
        else
        {

        cache.put("DbFoto",null)
         sessionScope.put ( "dbFotoConfig" ,null )
        }           

    } 

    return result ; 
} , 


    /* Here would be much more of these functions */ 


    /* Utility functions for cache management */ 

/* Retrieves the configuration object from a cache store. 
   There are many ways to do that */ 
getCacheObject : function ( ) { 
    // Consider carefully where to cache. Typical places 
    // are sessions or applications 
    var curCache = sessionScope. get ( "dbFotoConfig" ) ; 
    if (curCache == null ) { 
        curCache = new java. util. HashMap ( ) ; 
        sessionScope. put ( "dbFotoConfig" ,curCache ) ; 
    } 

    return curCache ;     
} , 

/* Resets the cache */ 
reset : function ( ) { 
    var curCache = new java. util. HashMap ( ) ; 
    sessionScope. put ( "dbFotoConfig" ,curCache ) ; 
} 
}
var dbRHConfig = {

getDbRH : function ( ) { 

var cache = this. getCacheObject ( ) ;

var result = cache. get ( "DbRH" ) ;

if (result == null ) {

    // Here is where you would do @DBSomething or worse
    var visao:NotesView=database.getView("Configuracoes")
    var doc:NotesDocument=visao.getFirstDocument();
    if (doc!=null)
    {

        result=[doc.getItemValueString("servidor_RH"),doc.getItemValueString("base_RH"),doc.getItemValueString("visao_RH")]
        cache.put("DbRH",result)
         sessionScope.put ( "dbRHConfig" ,cache )
    }
    else
    {

        cache.put("DbRH",null)
     sessionScope.put ( "dbRHConfig" ,null )
    }


} 

return result ; 
} , 


/* Here would be much more of these functions */ 


/* Utility functions for cache management */ 

/* Retrieves the configuration object from a cache store. 
There are many ways to do that */ 
getCacheObject : function ( ) { 
// Consider carefully where to cache. Typical places 
// are sessions or applications 
var curCache = sessionScope. get ( "dbRHConfig" ) ; 
if (curCache == null ) { 
    curCache = new java. util. HashMap ( ) ; 
    sessionScope. put ( "dbRHConfig" ,curCache ) ; 
} 

return curCache ;     
} , 

/* Resets the cache */ 
reset : function ( ) { 
var curCache = new java. util. HashMap ( ) ; 
sessionScope. put ( "dbRHConfig" ,curCache ) ; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred option is to create a normal document, save it, then call `setUniversalID()` to change it to something custom using `session.evaluate("@Password(\"whateverYouWant\")")`. @Password hashes the value to a 32-character hexadecimal string (i.e. a valid UNID). This allows you to easily retrieve the document (a normal document, so avoiding the caching issues of Profile documents) using `Database.getDocumentByUnid()` which is one of the quickest ways to access a document. You can store the "UNID" in an applicationScope variable if you want to avoid calculating it every time.

Comment: But how would that be?
When creating the document call the function setUniversalID () using as argument session.evaluate ("@ Password (\" whateverYouWant \ ")). Would it be this?
And to access the document use Database.getDocumentByUnid (). One question, do you suggest storing UNID in a session variable, correct? To store I will have to use the formula session.evaluate ("@ Password (\" whateverYouWant \ ")"), correct? And will it always bring the same value to the same argument?

Comment: How can you be sure your hash does not conflict with another already existing document?

Answer (score 0):

Please, please, don't do that. Unlearn SSJS and take XPages for what it is as much as you can: an IBM Domino flavored JSF framework implementation.

First of all you need to determine for how long you want the configuration to stick around, and if it's the same to every user.

If it's the same to every use best thing you can do is to store it in an **application scoped** bean. The application scope is shared with every user, instantiated once and lasts for the entire application's life.

The **session scoped** bean instead stays with the current user and it's visible by the current user only.

Managed beans' life is, yeah, managed by the framework. The framework takes care of instantiating it upon being referenced anywhere in the application. It gets distributed by a variable name that you decide when you configure it in the `faces-config.xml` document of your XPage application.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>app</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>demo.bean.ApplicationBean
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

The **managed-bean-name** declares the variable name your bean is available under. The **managed-bean-scope** says for how long the bean lives.

Now what you need to do is to create a Java class under the package **demo.bean** and by the name of **ApplicationBean** (that's what's in the example above, you can name it anything you prefer though).
From the way you named your variables it seems to me you need more of an application scoped bean than a session one. So, just for conversation's sake I write a sample of what that Application bean could look like for you given the code you posted above

```
package demo.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.FacesException;

import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.View;

import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils;

public class ApplicationBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Just a way to do it without repeating the same lines over and over
    private static final String[] CONFIG_FIELD_PREFIXES = { "servidor", "base", "visao" };

    private Map<String, String> dbFoto;
    private Map<String, String> dbRh;

    public Map<String, String> getDbFoto() {
        if (dbFoto == null) {
            loadConfig();
        }

        return dbFoto;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDbRh() {
        if (dbRh == null) {
            loadConfig();
        }

        return dbRh;
    }

    private void loadConfig() {
        dbFoto = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dbRh = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try {
            View vw = DominoUtils.getCurrentDatabase().getView("Configuracoes");
            Document doc = vw.getFirstDocument();

            if (doc != null) {
                for (String fieldName : CONFIG_FIELD_PREFIXES) {
                    dbFoto.put(fieldName, doc.getItemValueString(fieldName + "_foto"));
                    dbRh.put(fieldName, doc.getItemValueString(fieldName + "_RH"));
                }
            }
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            throw new FacesException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        dbFoto = null;
        dbRh = null;
    }

}
```

There are a few concepts there. Hope I'm not flooding you with too many of them. But to explain it briefly: first of all, beans work most of the time in lazy loading, meaning you don't preload data upon their creation but you let the class be populated as external sources call its methods. First time the method is called it loads and caches the data (you don't need to worry about its persistency because, remember, that is guaranteed by the framework and its life-span determined in the `faces-config.xml`). The second time the method is called it will serve the cached data (what you see in the Map objects declared at the beginning of the class). Considered the fact that you load 2 db configs from the same place it costs less to load both db configs at once rather than lazy loading them at separate times - that's the reason why I wrote the private method `loadConfig`.

Now what happens is that the configs are stored in a map and thanks to EL expressions you can read data from such map in a concise way.
If you create an XPage with the following code you will see everything coming alive on the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:text value="#{app.dbFoto.servidore} #{app.dbFoto.base} #{app.dbFoto.visao}" />

    <xp:text value="#{app.dbHr.servidore} #{app.dbHr.base} #{app.dbHr.visao}" />

    <xp:button id="button1" value="reset">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" action="#{app.reset}" />
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

`app` is our bean name `dbFoto` / `dbHr` is our call to `Map<String, String> getDbFoto( / Map<String, String> getDbHr(` (the `get` is dropped and the first letter lowercased, that's the convention to abide by), and each name is the key to access the map value.

I also provided a helper method to clear the configuration in case you needed it: `reset()`. It just nullifies the 2 variables that will therefore be fetched again the first time they are asked again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to implement.